# Problem with adding google calendars in Evolution - "Forbidden"

Tags: 14.04, unity, evolution, google-calendar

I'm trying to set up my Google calendars on Evolution. When I add my gmail account it correctly imports the main calendar. However, when I try to add additional calendars I run into problems.

If I do New --> Calendar --> Google, enter my username and password, and then try to retrieve the list of calendars I get this raw html shown:

```
Authentication required: <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Fobidden</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Forbidden</H1>
<H2>Error 403</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

If I try to add it via New --> Calendar --> On the web, and use the XML link I get a message:

```
Error loading calendar 'Unnamed'
Unable to connect to 'Unnamed': Cannot open calendar: Forbidden
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: First remove or disable UOA integration. And use caldav method instead of Google(Or right click on primary calendar & select properties). In the url field it should be something like: `https://www.google.com/calendar/dav/YOURUSERNAME@gmail.com/events`. Use your full user name for both username & email. Then click on find calendars. Enter your password. Does this help?

Comment: @Khurshid-Alam it almost works. I can access the calendar and add new invites (so thank you!). However, if I try to edit existing events I get "Authentication Failed". That's not a showstopper for me though.

Comment: Yes. That's probably a bug. Try restarting evolution-data-server( a reboot will do).A better way to sync google calendar is to use [syncevolution](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution/). Find instruction here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution/synchronize-multiple-google-calendars-with-evolution-calendars

Comment: Reboot didn't fix it. I may take a look at syncevolution - I'd seen it when searching earlier but I was hoping for Evolution to work on its on. Do you want to post your comments as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what you should do:

- First remove or disable UOA integration.
- And use caldav method instead of Google(Or right click on primary calendar & select properties).
- In the url field it should be something like:

  `https://www.google.com/calendar/dav/YOURUSERNAME@gmail.com/events`.
- Use your full user name for both username & email. Then click on find calendars. Enter your password.
- Select the desired calendar & click apply. It will appear in evolution.
- Repeat above steps for other calendars.

DONE!

---

Another way to sync google calendar with caldav & UOA is to use [syncevolution](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution/synchronize-multiple-google-calendars-with-evolution-calendars).

Comment: Also works on Debian Jessie (Evolution 3.12). No need to disable anything though; just add CalDav calendars instead of Google calendars in addition to the default Google calendar.